# Xamarin iOS Library can't get location

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, stripe-payments

I have a vendor provided `.framework` file that I created an iOS binding project for using Objective Sharpie. I can call into the library, get callbacks, pull data, mostly everything works except the library being able to access the current location. The public headers for that project are here [StripeTerminal](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-ios/tree/master/PublicHeaders)

In my C# code, I used the Xamarin.Essentials to pull the current location.

```
var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
```

This returns with my location both in the simulator and on a real iPhone. I can see the access is granted to my app in the Privacy-> Location Services menu.

I have the below in my `info.plist` file, which I have tried targeting 9.0 SDK and 12.0 SDK.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location required for accepting payments.</string>
```

In an example XCode project provided by the vendor, that is able to pull the location by inspecting their verbose logs. In the Xamarin app, their logs get stuck on a `requestLocation` and never continue past it. I even tried setting the Link option to `Don't Link` and the result is the same.

What is wrong with my binding project that would prevent a native framework library from being able to access the location?

Comment: Maybe, your vendor iOS Framework is actually using another library / framework to access the location data ? If that's the case, then this dependency MUST be added into your binding project as a reference. In iOS dependencies are not embedded into a .Framework archive

Comment: Their sample project just has Static.framework and AlamoFire.framework as linked/embed in their project. Both used to write the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was a mix of how Xamarin works and iOS. I created a `CLLocationManager` object in my C# code and setup a listener for location changes, except it never worked. So I tried the `Xamarin.Essentials` package to get the current location using `GetLastKnownLocationAsync` and that worked every time, so it wasn't a permission issue or a simulator issue. Digging into the `Xamarin.Essentials` code I found the below.

```
NSRunLoop.Main.InvokeOnMainThread(() => manager = new CLLocationManager());
```

Reading more documentation, I found that the `CLLocationManager` can only be successfully created from an active run loop. Wrapping calls into the Stripe Terminal iOS SDK in the `NSRunLoop.Main.InvokeOnMainThread` allowed things to work as they were creating a `CLLocationManager` expecting the call to be in an active run loop without checking first, or documenting that behavior. Stripe's internal code waited on a callback, which never happened, thus hanging the SDK in a weird state.

Comment: Kudos to you man, I've spent multiple hours pulling my hairs out ;)